# Windows analog of $1 (PID of the last started process)

Tags: windows, vbscript, pid

How to get on Windows PID of the last started process using WScript.Shell or similar?

I know how to start a process and get its PID:

```
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec( program )
Set pid = oExec.ProcessID
```

Now the problem is that the program is another batch (or could be VBScript). The batch starts a real program which PID I would like to get.

On Linux (shell script) it is very easy to do. just `pid=$!`

But what can I do on Windows?

Comment: Why not just return the PID as the return value (or just send it to stdout) using VBScript?

Comment: Thanks. I think the return value is limited to 256. But it seems like the only way (with reasonable effort) is reading stdout in the VBScript. I think I can use `oExec.StdOut` property but never tried it so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no equivalent of $! In Windows.

In case you wish to retrieve the PID of the third process, you can search for it using WMI. A example of this could be found [here](http://lantoolbox.com/scripts/list-processes-wmi-win32_process-vbscript/) (just searching and displaying the information) or [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1154650&page=1) (searching and killing the process).

If the executable of the third name is not known, you might want to use a *Job object* which groups several processes into one object. And you could easily kill all of them at once with *TerminateJobObject*.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx) for a quick overview or [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604522/performing-equivalent-of-kill-process-tree-in-c-on-windows).

However, I don’t know if these methods can be used from VBScript.

Comment: Cannot vote it up :( Not enough reputation.

Comment: Do it when you have enough rep - just kidding, not a problem. If the information was helpful, that's enough for me.